# Slack pull request integration

Tags: github, slack

Is there a way to set up a git hook to alert a developer when someone has commented on their pull request. It is frustrating that I stumble on a comment days after it has been posted

Comment: You should generally get email notifications when someone comments on a PR you're watching.  But yes, there is a Github integration for Slack.

Comment: yeah. email notifications works pretty well actually.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the new [github](https://slack.com/apps/A8GBNUWU8-github) app in the Slack App Directory. It sends notification about almost every change on your git to Slack, including comments.

Answer (score 0):

The main project for GitHub/Slack integration is [`github.com/integrations/slack`](https://github.com/integrations/slack).
It does include [repository activity](https://github.com/integrations/slack#repository-activity):

> Subscribe to an Organization or a Repository On repositories, the app notifies of open, close, and re-open events on pull requests and issues in repositories you've subscribed to.
> It also notifies of any push directly to the repository's default branch **as well as comments on issues and pull requests**.

However, regarding comments, see [issue 578](https://github.com/integrations/slack/issues/578):

> If issue is closed with a comment, the comment should be included in the Slack notification
>
> A lot of times the final comment has some context on why the issue is being closed (e.g. fixed, duplicate, something else). If someone clicks the "comment and close" button, it seems helpful to include that comment to the "issue closed" Slack notification.

So you don't *always* have every comment every time.

Note: today, GitHub adds "[New improvements to the Slack and GitHub integration](https://blog.github.com/2018-05-17-new-improvements-to-slack-and-github-integration/)", namely new Slack commands, but nothing regarding comments.